# How to wait for 30 hours?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to wait for a long period of time (for example: 30 hours) with a maximum delay of 2 or 3 seconds. I have read that `Sleep()` and `WM_TIMER` are not accurate, and could wait for minutes past this specified time.

The only solution that seems practical is to use `GetTickCount()`, so should I use it or are there other solutions?

Comment: Have you thought about using the clock/calendar built in your computer?

Comment: the sleep function (can be up to 1 second slow) puts the process on the execution queue then the elapsed time has passed.  How soon it actually executes, depends on its' 'nice' factor, how many other processes (of equal or higher priority) are waiting to execute, and similar considerations.  Minutes delay is very unlikely

Comment: I'd try a [Waitable Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @user3629249 So Windows will wait exactly 30 hours, and then put my process (or thread I suppose?) in the execution queue, and so the delay comes from the time taken for my process to get its turn to execute, correct?

Comment: Why not try it?  Print out the time.  Sleep for, say, 8 hours overnight, then print out the time again.

Comment: @Martin James If it worked one time, it doesn't mean it will work every time.

Comment: It works how you suggest above.  After 30 hours + some small tens of ms, your sleepy thread will become ready and, hopefully, running.

Comment: Years ago, I tried timing Sleep() over an hour with a manual stopwatch.  I could not detect any discrepancy.  Not tried it with 30 hours, but the approach suggested by David H. below of 'creeping up' on the expiry time with pregressively smaller sleeps, continually adjusted by referrring to the real-time clock, is a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is not a real time OS. There are no facilities in Windows that can make any such guarantees.

Given that you can do something like this:

1. Wait for 1/2 of the time.
2. Wait for 1/2 of the time remaining.
3. And so on until your wait is less than your desired accuracy.

But even then, does the clock on a Windows machine tell time to your desired accuracy?

If you really care about accuracy of timing you need a real time OS and probably a dedicated clock with a guaranteed and known accuracy.

Comment: I would make it 3/4 or 7/8 (since 4 or 8 are power of twos, but not 10)

Comment: @David Heffernan So `GetTickCount()` will not work? If not I guess the only guaranteed solution is to use the system clock (even though this has the disadvantage of someone changing the time).

Comment: Get an external clock that tells reliable time.

Comment: @David Heffernan What is an "external clock", is it a hardware component?

Comment: The user can rely on [Task Scheduler API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx). There is a time specific [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383619(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would try `Sleep()` and `WM_TIMER` for 1 or 2 hour test sessions and see how far it is off and multiply the difference times 30hrs to see what your delay will be. If it is to long then try `GetTickCount()`

Comment: Yes!   Test it,  By far the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Read current time with `GetLocalTime` in WM_TIMER events and check for necessary HH:MM:SS.

PS: Use `GetTickCount64` instead of `GetTickCount`.